# Clickonce installer downloads updated files from server unnecessarily

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a clickonce installer that updates itself from my website. For the initial installation, I zip the install files for download and my clients download it.

Recently I have noticed that the installer will re-download all the install files, even though the most recent is available locally from the zip. Even stranger, if the update has an older version than that in the downloaded installer, it will revert to the version available on the web site - even though it is a downgrade.

Is this the expected behaviour? If not, how can I make it work properly.

Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood, you're zip copy of web hosted application, and clients just unzip and launch **setup.exe** or **app.application** files. In this way it works correct, because deployment application root is located on web server and zip copy doing nothing, you just launch click-once entry point file. Application deployment location is **app.application** file in codebase  tag.

Also your launched application remember location for future updates checks, therefor if you'll try to change from mage.exe ProviderUrl (for example) to C:\YourApplication\app.application (before zipping) and you will be sure that clients will unzip in C:\YourApplication folder for update it will break your web site update check point for deployed before application.

So, no way...

Comment: Sadly, it appears this is the case;

More reading here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/deployment/deployment-element-clickonce-deployment